# warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ using argv

Tags: c, printf, argv

I don't even know what is happening, I just started a new project and setup a basic cat just to make sure everything was working, and this happened.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    printf("%s",argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

That's it, I reinstalled gcc, g++, and both multilibs. I really have no clue what to even think.

Comment: It should be char **argv, it's an array of strings, not a single string

Comment: `char *argv` typo as `char **argv`

Comment: @EricRenouf; Its not array of string. Its pointer to pointer to `char`.

Comment: @hacks ok it's an array of pointers to chars, which in this case will be null terminated sequences of chars which are typically used to represent strings in c

Comment: Did you enable all, some, or no warnings? I'm pretty sure there is a bunch of warnings regarding the prototype of `main`.

Comment: For the standard libraries, you should use "<...>" to search the system paths.

Answer (score 7):

The declared type of `argv` is wrong.  The signature of `main` should be one of:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]); // Functionally equivalent to above
```

Note that `main` can also take `void` to ignore parameters, but this is not what you're looking for here.

I personally prefer the second form listed above as I find it more intuitive (array of `char*`) vs the first (pointer to `char*`), but since arrays are merely pointer arithmetic in C, either will do.

Comment: I must be drunk or something similar, you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The second argument to the `main` function is normally defined as `char **argv` or as `char *argv[]`; both ways are correct.

And the include sentences are also wrong. With `#include "file.h"` it will look after `file.h` in the current folder, but if your are including a header file from C standard library, it should be `#include <file.h>`.

Comment: The notation `#include "stdio.h"` normally works OK, but you're right that the standard uses `#include <stdio.h>` and you should do so too unless there are extraordinary reasons to do otherwise.